# jQuery - User function into a plugin

Tags: jquery, function, plugins

I'm making a little plugin. This is a full page plugin, once you scroll, it scrolls the whole view to the next one.

The thing is, I would like that give the user the possibility to add a function once the page has finished scrolling to the section.

Working fiddle (trying to comment the code for basic functionalities): https://jsfiddle.net/gx1kf7ee/1/

I was trying to override the onLoad property:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    anchors: [],
    showHistory: true,
    section: "section",
    easing: "easeInOutQuart",
    speed: 1000,
    onLoad: function() {}
}, opts);
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fullPage").fullPage({
        anchors: ["first", "second", "third"],
        showHistory: true,
        speed: 500,
        onLoad: function() {
            alert("Hello");
        }
    });
});
```

But it clearly doesn't works that way.

Any help with this?

Comment: What happens if you change settings.onLoad to settings.onLoad() in resize animate and changeSection animate functions ?

Comment: @PrashantMajhwar oh, thanks for that! it works now ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call it as a function. 
Instead of
`settings.onload`
you run it as
`settings.onload()`
and it should work.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't even thought about it! Thanks a lot!